# Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

So there is my problem. I'm working to a project and intitally was made with bootstrap 2. Now i want to change the codesto bootstrap 3, but i've encountered some issues. Can someone  help me to change the following part?

```html
<body>
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        
        <a href="#" class="brand">Brand</a>
        
         <nav class="pull-right">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
         </nav>
        </div><!-- end navbar inner -->
       </div><!-- end navbar -->
       
        <div class="hero-unit-inner text-center">
        <h1>Text</h1>
        <h4>Text </h4>
        
        <a href="#" class="btn">Get Started</a>
        <a href="#" >Learn More</a>

        <img src="img/browser.png">
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of container -->
    </div><!-- end jumbotron -->
   
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Bootstrap 3 code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                    <a href="#" class="brand">Brand</a>
                    <nav class="pull-xs-right">
                        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
                            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
                            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>
                <!-- end navbar inner -->
            </div>
            <!-- end navbar -->
            <div class="hero-unit-inner text-xs-center">
                 <h1>Text</h1>
                 <h4>Text </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Get Started</a>
                    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                    <img src="img/browser.png" />
            </div>
    </div><!-- end jumbotron -->        
 </div><!-- end of container -->
```

http://getbootstrap.com/migration/ for a list of class changes, depredations etc.

Comment: Thank you. You really help me to open my eyes. The solution was prety similar to your response. Thanx for your time.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Please feel welcome to mark your question answered and/or up my response :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I must have missed that one... It becomes "jumbrotron". See the link I shared so you can match up the classes. http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's CSS. Keep in mind that some classes have changed while other have been deprecated.

If you used a theme to build your site with, then I advise having a look at the site where you downloaded the template as in most cases they update the templates...